# Area of intersection of a circle with a rectangle

Tags: java, algorithm, math, geometry

I want to find the area of a given circle that comes under the region of a given rectangle. I searched many posts on stackoverflow but they are not satisfying. I followed this post
 http://www.eex-dev.net/index.php?id=100
But it doesn't seem accurate.
I'd appreciate if someone provides me a good accurate solution atleast upto 10^-6 precision.
Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to adapt the code at the site above to get the accuracy you need.  If you aren't getting the sufficient accuracy, pick a smaller step size as the basis for the numerical integration.  Otherwise, consider the various cases and solve it algebraically for each case.

Comment: I have tried all that.. I failed and that's why I asked a question here.

Answer (score 2):

Linked article uses integration method of left rectangle rule that suffers from precision loss (here value is underestimated because envelope is convex or straight).

You can use more precise approaches such as [Simpson's rule or Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Quadrature_rules_based_on_interpolating_functions).

Moreover, every configuration might be subdivided into simple parts - rectangle, triangle, circle segment with known exact area formula!